# How to unserialize an array string

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

This is how I create the array

```
var list = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray');

$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: " some path ",
       data: { "list" : JSON.stringify(list) },
       success: function(data) {}
});
```

In DB it looks like that

```
["34","37","38","40","41","42","43","44","45","48","49","50"]
```

No I want to use this as array in php. How can I convert this string to an array? I tried with `unserialize()` method but this does not seem the way to go.

Comment: PHP's `unserialize` is _only_ for strings serialized with PHP's `serialize`, you are actually sending JSON, so, `json_decode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST["list"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not stringify the json object, let jQuery handle that for you.

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: " some path ",
       data: { "list" : list }, // here, it's not necessary to stringify the json object.
       success: function(data) {}
});
```

Then you get the array in php by `$_POST['list']`.